# Displaying icons using php IF

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Just wondering, I'm creating a multi-vendor website. So far it has all been going well, however we have a need to display icons as badges if a field contains data.

Here is an example of the code:

```
<li class="location clearfix">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <span><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i><?php _e('abn ',) ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <?php echo $abn; ?>
        </div>
    </li>
```

When displaying the field `abn` it appears fine, although we are wanting an icon displayed if `abn` contains data. We are needing the Echo to be an IF statement, that if the profile ``abn``` field contains data, that an icon is displayed.

Just wondering, is there any examples that anyone would have using an existing script?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: So you want an example of an if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
add if condition with !empty()

```
<?php if(!empty($abn)) {?>
<li class="location clearfix">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <span><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i><?php _e('abn ',) ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <?php echo $abn; ?>
    </div>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

you can add this if condition wherever you want to hide or display data.

Comment: Perfect thank you, that worked! 

I added in a php echo to display an image as well. Thank you very much for helping!